# Obtener datos de una relación de muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, eloquent

buen dia

tengo unos select dependientes  al escoger una maquina se debe listar en otro select los productos relacionados a esa maquina seria una relacion mucho a muchos para este tengo una tabla pivote donde estan las diferentes combinaciones  funciona bien al escojer la maquina me lista solo las combinaciones de la tabla pivote pero me aparece el id como hago para aceder al nombre del producto  ???

gracias de antemano

**base**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**select**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui me aparece el id de la columna producto de la tabla pivote como hago para traer el nombre de la tabla producto por medio de la tabla pivote

**ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // asignar los select a las variables   
        var plantSelect = $('#maquina');
        var areaSelect = $('#id_producto');
        // obteniendo las maquinas y llenando el select
        function populatePlantSelect() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('getmaquinas') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
                        plantSelect.append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.nombre_maquina + "</option>");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Hubo un error obteniendo las maquinas!');
                }
            });
        }
        populatePlantSelect();
        // indica la maquina y lista los productos asignados a esa maquina 
        plantSelect.change(function(){
            var plantId = $(this).val();
            areaSelect.empty();
    
            if (plantId) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('getproducto') }}",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { maquina: plantId },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        areaSelect.append('<option value=""></option>')
                        $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
                            areaSelect.append("<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.codigo    +'__'+ value.producto  + "</option>");
                        });
                    },
                    error : function(){
                        alert('Hubo un error obteniendo los productos!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        // despues de selecionar le producto asigna codigo de producto para llenar campo de la imagen y cargar
        
    });
    </script>
```

**controlador**

```
 public function getmaquinas(){

    try{
        $linea = linea::all();
        $response = ['data' => $linea];
    }catch (\Exception $exception){

        return response ()->json(['mensaje'=>'upps hubo un error'],500);
    }
    return response()->json($response);
}

public function getproducto(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $id_maquina = $request->input('maquina');
        $producto = pivote_m_p::when($id_maquina, function ($query) use ($id_maquina)
         {
            $query->where('maquina', $id_maquina);
        })->get();

        $response = ['data'=> $producto];
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception){

        return response ()->json(['mensaje'=>'upps hubo un error'],500);
    }

    return response ()->json($response);
}
```

esto ya tiene las rutas en web php
creo que la solucion esta en acomodar $producto pero no se como

**modelo**

```
    class pivote_m_p extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;



    protected $table='PIVOTE_M_P';


    public function productos(){


        return $this->hasMany(Registrouno::class);
    }

    public function maquina(){


        return $this->hasMany(linea::class);
    }
}
```

**modelo de la maquina**

```
    class linea extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $table="TABLA-MAQUINAS";



}
```

**modelo productos**

```
    class Registrouno extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $table="PRODUCTO";
    



}
```

ayuda :(

Comment: mmm para aceder a las combinaciones no se estuvo mal  ???? es necesari  el modelo

Comment: ya agrege los modelos

Comment: si señor escoger la maquina y que solo se listen los productos que tienen esa maquina pero quiero los nombres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

1. No es necesario un modelo para la tabla *intermedia* entonces yo optaría por eliminarlo, aunque si decides usarlo entonces trata de ajustar [a lo indicado por Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)
2. Las relaciones que defines en el modelo antes mencionado no se ajustan a tu escenario
3. En los modelos *Producto* y *Maquina* debes declarar la relación que los vincula con la tabla intermedia (dicha relación es [**`belongsToMany`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure)) de esta forma:

**Nota importante**: Para la propuesta de solución yo no haré uso de un modelo para la tabla `PIVOTE_M_P`

Modelo Producto:

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    /*
        Resto de tu código
    */
    public function maquinas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Maquina::class, 'PIVOTE_M_P', 'producto', 'maquina');
    }
}
```

Modelo Maquina:

```
class Maquina extends Model
{
    /*
        Resto de tu código
    */
    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class, 'PIVOTE_M_P', 'maquina', 'producto');
    }
}
```

Como notas en ambos casos:

- Tuvimos que pasar 3 argumentos extra, sugiero leas [este recurso](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure)

Entonces la consulta debe ser tan simple como:

```
$maquinaConProductos = Maquina::with('productos')->findOrFail($idMaquina);
```

O bien si quieres todas las máquinas con todos sus productos vinculados:

```
$maquinasConProductos = Maquina::with('productos')->get();
```

Donde:

- Para el primer caso obtendrías un objeto con los datos de la maquina recuperada y una colección con los productos asociados
- Para el segundo caso obtendrías una colección de todas las máquinas y por cada objeto una colección asociada con los productos asociados

Comment: la cabeza me hizo "puffff"  pero funciono  me la verdad no se como voy a leer lo que me enviaste para saber como  gracias  :)